# No volver a un activity anterior

Tags: android, base-de-datos, android-layout, android-fragment

El caso es que quiero que cuando la aplicación se ejecute por primera vez, se muestre el primer activity de PresentacionActivity y que cuando el usuario presione botón continuar vaya al siguiente activity, se inicie la MainActivity. Luego de esto, que ya no vuelva a aparecer dicha PresentacionActivity.

lo que deseo es el activity de PresentacionActivity se muestre solo una ves.El caso es que quiero que cuando la aplicación se ejecute por primera vez, se muestre el primer activity de PresentacionActivity y que cuando el usuario presione botón continuar vaya al siguiente activity, se inicie la MainActivity. Luego de esto, que ya no vuelva a aparecer dicha PresentacionActivity.

lo que deseo es el activity de PresentacionActivity se muestre solo una ves i q no se vuelva a mostrar.ia use el finish y otros metodos pero al momento de cerrar la aplicacion por completo se vuelve al a PresentacionActivity....alguien puede ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que agregué a tu anterior pregunta la cual me parece sería la misma, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194390/no-volver-al-activty-anterior en realidad debes llamar finish() para cerrar la activity a la cual no deseas regresar. Te sugiero agregar el código que hayas tratado en tus preguntas, eso ayudará a otros usuarios que tengan la misma pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta el metodo `finish()` al momento de navegar a la actividad:

```
startActivity....
finish();//...
```

Este metodo elimina la actividad invocadara del stack de navegacion.

**Importante**: recuerda siempre ejecutar el metodo finish() **despues** del `startActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente llama [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) después de iniciar `MainActitiy`, esto para finalizar la `PresentacionActivity` y no vuelva a mostrarse, ya que si se mantiene aparecería al cerrar `MainActivity`, este es un ejemplo:

```
 //Abre MainActivity desde PresentacionActivity.
 Intent intent = new Intent(PresentacionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 //Finaliza PresentacionActitiy.
  finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Por qué no mejor usas otra activity para tu presentación y dejas MainActivity para el uso normal de tu app.

Cuando cargues por primera vez MainActivity lanza inmediatamente tu Activity de presentación desde `onStart`, y cuando finalizen de ver tu presentación guarda un valor en `SharedPreference` para después saber si debes volver a mostrar la presentación o No.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(!presentacionVista){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, presentacionActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente.

En el Manifest agrega esto al tag del activity que sera la pantalla de Bienvenida.

```
        android:noHistory="true"
```

Esto ayuda a que si el usuario presiona el boton de atras no volvera a la pantalla de Bienvenida,quedaria asi.

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.example.example.example.Bienvenida"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />
```

Al Ejecutarse por primera vez la aplicacion y al Presionar el Boton Siguiente Lo que haremos sera crear una Preferencia.Crearemos un metodo.

```
public void CargarPreferencias(Activity contex, String inicio){
    SharedPreferences Preferencias = contex.getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Preferencias.edit();
    editor.putString("inicio",inicio);
    editor.apply();
}
```

El codigo de forma Resumida quedaria asi.Activity Bienvenida.

```
public class Bienvenida extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button acceder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



    acceder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.procesar_login);
    assert acceder != null;
    acceder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
            Creamos la Preferencia y guardamos el valor del Key inicio=Inciado.
             */
            CargarPreferencias(Bienvenida.this,"Inciado");
        }
    });



  }


  /*
   Creamos la Preferencia y guardamos el valor del Key inicio
  */
 public  void CargarPreferencias(Activity contex, String inicio){
    SharedPreferences Preferencias = contex.getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Preferencias.edit();
    editor.putString("inicio",inicio);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

En nuestro Activity Main Quedaria asi.

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button acceder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

}

 /*Este Metodo es un ciclo de vida de un Activity y se ejecuta justo antes de crear la vista*/

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    /*
    Verificamos si el user ya vio la Bienvenida si ya la vio no hacemos nada y se muestra el activity Main.
    Pero si es la primera vez Llamamos al Activity Bienvenida.
     */
    /*si es distinto a Inciado Llamamos a la Presentacion*/
    if(!getPreferencia(ActivityMain.this).equals("Inciado")){
        Intent acceso = new Intent(this ,Bienvenida.class);
        startActivity(acceso);
    }

}

    /*
    Funcion que retorna el valor de la preferencia con key inicio
     */

public  String getPreferencia(Activity contex){
    SharedPreferences prefs =contex.getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  prefs.getString("inicio","");
}








}
```

Answer (score -1):

En el manifiesto cambia para que su MainActivity sea el Inicializador de su aplicación.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Y quitale los "Intent-filter" a la actividad de PresentacionActivity

```
<activity
            android:name=".PresentacionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_configuracion"
            android:parentActivityName=".actividades.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
```

En el método onCreate de la actividad MainActivity, has el siguiente código:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, PresentacionActivity.class);    
 startActivity(intent, requestCode)...
```

Si abre otra actividad desde el `MainActivity` siempre regresaras a `MainActivity` y mientras no se ejecute de nuevo el método `onCreate` de `MainActivity` no se lanzará de nuevo PresentacionActivity

Para evitar que se lance de nuevo `PresentacionActivity` revisa los [ciclos de vida de un app](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=es-419) Android asi como los cambios en las actividades que ejecutan un `onCreate`.

Answer (score -1):

Si entendi bien, queres que solo se abra la primera vez que se ejecuta la app y nunca mas, si es asi la solucion seria asi:

En el manifest seteamos el MainActivity como Main y como Launcher para que sea el primero en ejecutar y desde ahi decidir si es la primera vez y corresponde abrir el PresentacionActivity o no:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".PresentacionActivity/>
```

En el MainActivity vamos a usar la SharedPreference para guardar un bool y asi saber si ya se mostro alguna vez esa pantalla

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(){
   ...
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   if(!prefs.getBoolean("isPresentacionShowed",false)){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, PresentacionActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Y en PresentacionActivity guardas true en la sharedPreferences

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(){
   ...
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("isPresentacionShowed",true);
   editor.apply();
}
```

De todas formas siempre recomiendo tener un activity Splash que se encargue de este tipo de redireccionamientos, porque de tener algun ciclo de vida mas complejo la app podria resultar engorroso manejarlo de esta manera.